# Adding autogenerated value to the database in Flask with pymongo

Tags: python-3.x, flask, pymongo, flask-wtforms, flask-admin

I have a code that insert name and email to the pymongo database. Here is my code;

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_admin import Admin, BaseView, expose
from flask_admin.contrib.pymongo import ModelView
from wtforms import Form
from pymongo import MongoClient
from wtforms import TextField, PasswordField
from uuid import uuid1
import secrets

# Create secret_key -> secret_key = str(uuid1())
# Create access_key -> access_key = secrets.token_urlsafe(8)

client = MongoClient()
db = client['AdminDB']

class UserForm(Form):
    name = TextField('Name')
    email = TextField('Email')

class UserView(ModelView):
    column_list = ('name', 'email')
    form = UserForm

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'mysecretKey'
admin = Admin(app, name='My App Admin')
admin.add_view(UserView(db['users']))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I want *secret_key* and *access_key* should be autogenerating in nature. My expected entry in the database collection is below.

```
_id:5f6f548d3cfa158e2ec35f42
name:"name"
email:"user@email.com"
secret_key: "b0f4f2ad-0009-11eb-8ac8-107d1a262dee"
access_key: "9LYZ8UYokGA"
```

How can I achieve this in my code? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Override the view's `on_model_change`. For example, to set the values when a model is newly created:

```
class UserView(ModelView)

    def on_model_change(form, model, is_created):

        if is_created:

            model.secret_key = str(uuid1())
            model.access_key = secrets.token_urlsafe(8)
```

Comment: I added the code inside the UserView. But getting the following error.

**AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'secret_key'**

Comment: I suspect you will need to add `secret_key` and `access_key` as fields (hidden fields might work) in your `UserForm`. Or, use PyMongo to update the model with new attributes and values.